# avoiding scipy eigs ArpackNoConvergence error

Tags: scipy

What causes the ArpackNoConvergence error in this scipy function?

The docs just say "When the requested convergence is not obtained", but don't give any information about what that actually means.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to efficiently calculate eigenvectors and eigenvalues analytically. Instead you use an iterative process to approximate them: you start with some guessed solution and try to improve it in every iteration.

The iterative process itself does not define a stop criterion. Obviously we want it to stop once our approximations are in very close proximity to the actual solution.

But sometimes we are improving our approximation very slowly and the number of steps to get to a good approximation would be enormous. Instead of letting the computer calculate for an undefined amount of time we may want to define a maximum number of iterations.

We say that the algorithm did not converge if after the maximum number of iterations (see the `maxiter` keyword), the current approximation is not sufficiently close (see the `tol` keyword) to the actual solution .